# Adding a list of emails to wp_mail() in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, email

I am trying to add a list of email addresses to wp_mail() from a certain user role. I have a comma delimited list stored as `$user_email_list` but cannot get that to output into the `$multiple_recipients` array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Get users and their roles, create list of emails to send notification to.
    $user_args = array(
      'role__in' => 'test_role', 
      'orderby'  => 'user_nicename',
      'order'    => 'ASC'
    );

    $users = get_users($user_args);

    foreach ( $users as $user ) :
      $user_email_list = $user->user_email . ', ';
    endforeach;

// Email Data
    $multiple_recipients = array(
        $user_email_list
    );
    $subject = $post->post_title;
    $body    = $post->post_content;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code of foreach and check your $multiple_recipients variable at final, it would be comma separated value.

```
foreach ( $users as $user ) :
  $user_email_list[] = $user->user_email;
endforeach;

$multiple_recipients = implode(', ', $user_email_list);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work upon sending the email I'm afraid? Not sending any emails  and browser window goes blank.

Comment: One another try is remove space after comma, but wp_mail also accept $to as array,

Comment: can you check first are you getting recipients properly by comma separated or not? then can you check SMTP by send test mail ? you can also check by first send an email from single user , if it is working or not?

Comment: @Dinoop: yes, i am just correcting OP's code as he want's as comma separated value.

Comment: If I hard code multiple email addresses; the emails send fine. SMTP is setup. If I output the code to the screen, then it seems correct. So I'm not sure why it's not working?

Comment: Codex example: `<?php $multiple_recipients = array(
    'recipient1@example.com',
    'recipient2@foo.example.com'
); ?>`

Comment: can you check and debug code why static emails are sending? can you print what is out put of $multiple_recipients during code ?

Comment: Working... had a semi colon where it shouldnt be!