# WordPress wp_mail not sending email if pass array variable

Tags: php, wordpress, email

On publish `event` CPT, I want to send emails to every participant set in the custom meta boxes.

When I pass `array` as email addresses it is not sending email

```
wp_mail( $employee_emails, $subject, $message );
```

but if I use string than sending an email. I don't understand what is wrong with the code or `wp_mail`

```
wp_mail( 'me@emailid.com', $subject, $message );
```

## My Code

```
function ac_send_event_notification( $ID, $post ) {

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $ID ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // employees details
    $employees  = rwmb_meta( 'ac_event_employees', [], $ID );
    $positions  = rwmb_meta( 'ac_event_positions', [], $ID );
    $operations = rwmb_meta( 'ac_event_operations', [], $ID );

    // event details
    $operation_user_ids = [];
    if ( ! empty( $operations ) ) {
        foreach ( $operations as $operation ) {
            $operation_user_ids[] = ac_get_event_participants_ids_by_operation( $operation );
        }
    }
    $position_user_ids = [];
    if ( ! empty( $positions ) ) {
        foreach ( $positions as $position ) {
            $position_user_ids[] = ac_get_event_participants_ids_by_position( $position );
        }
    }
    $operation_ids = array_reduce( $operation_user_ids, 'array_merge', [] );
    $position_ids  = array_reduce( $position_user_ids, 'array_merge', [] );

    sort( $employees );
    sort( $operation_ids );
    sort( $position_ids );

    $employee_ids_to_notify = array_unique( array_merge( $employees, $operation_ids, $position_ids ) );
    sort( $employee_ids_to_notify );

    // get employees email ids
    if ( ! empty( $employee_ids_to_notify ) ) {
        foreach ( $employee_ids_to_notify as $employee ) {
            $employee_emails[] = get_the_author_meta( 'email', $employee );
        }
    }

    // Sending email to the participants

    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name   = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );

    $subject = sprintf( 'New Event Created by %s', $name );
    $message = "Hello,\n\n";
    $message .= "There is a new event created by {$name}.\n\n";
    $message .= "Check out all details with the following link.\n\n";
    $message .= get_the_permalink( $ID );

    wp_mail( $employee_emails, $subject, $message );

}
add_action( 'publish_event', 'ac_send_event_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: `var_dump($employee_emails);` shows what?

Comment: @CBroe I have already debug before posting. It is giving an array of email IDs

Comment: @CBroe Additionally, I have just tested calling the function `ac_send_event_notification()` in the `single.php` and it is sending an email when the page loads. So I believe there must be something wrong with the hook or with my code for `HOOK`

Comment: @CBroe again I have checked with `var_dump($employee_emails)` and I got this result. `array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "me@myemailid.com" }` Only one email as I haven't set more recipients but only one for the testing.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630777/adding-a-list-of-emails-to-wp-mail-in-wordpress?rq=1

Comment: @GNANA thanks for the link but I have tried out everything including `implode()` nothing works. It is only sending email if I add as a string. :(

Comment: Just paste here your array($employee_emails)

Comment: @GNANA [here is the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670703/wordpress-wp-mail-not-sending-email-if-pass-array-variable?noredirect=1#comment76327106_44670703)

Comment: Are you using any plugins that modify wp_mail function such as Sendgrid and the likes?

Comment: @trainoasis Do you mean `WP SMTP Mail`? yes, I have setup SMTP for local dev env.

Comment: That too yea. Array should still work though, but I've ran into the same problem with passing array when using external plugins, just saying. You havent figured it out by now?

Comment: @trainoasis I am still looking for a solution. Because of the project deadline, I have used a loop to send emails. Let me know if you find any.

Answer (score 0):

I Used like below, Its worked perfectly.

```
$employee_emails = array( 'test@gmail.com', 'testsecond@gmail.com' );

wp_mail( $employee_emails, 'subject', 'test message' );
```

**OR** try below method, Its not good practice!,

```
foreach($group_emails as $email_address)
{
   wp_mail($email_address, 'my subject', 'my message', $headers);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong in my code. Everything is correct and still not sending an email. I have tried array, implode but no luck.